# C# Properties doesn't exist

Tags: c#, .net, file, properties

I've been trying to use the built in settings feature in C# but it's not working. When I try and do something like `this.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.myColor;`, `Properties` doesn't exist. I've tried looking up more info but microsoft provides no info regarding this. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Do you have an app.settings file?

Comment: Are you `using` the namespace that `Properties` is in...

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to create your Settings in your Project  Property's Settings section. You do not show how you create it but something like this should work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Create the setting for myColor**

1. In Solution Explorer, expand the Properties node of your project.
2. Double-click the .settings file in which you want to add a new
   setting. The default name for this file is Settings.settings.
3. In the Settings designer, set the Name, Value, Type, and Scope for
   your setting. Each row represents a single setting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx